# Using PIP from Anaconda env - cannot see installed packages

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am using anaconda. I created an environment and I am trying to install packages.
However, some of the packages are not available via conda so I am trying to install the via pip (actually from a local file, so I typed "pip install -e local_package_dir). Unfortunately, I cannot see the in the installed list...
Some information:
I activated the envioronment.
"which pip" returns '/Programs/miniconda3/envs/env_oncotator19/bin/pip'
When I try to run python from the command line, and import the package, it exists, but when I do "conda list" it does not appear.

The reason I am concerned about it is that when I am running an external package which requires as dependencies specific versions of packages, and I suspect that since conda cannot find the installed package, it moves using the system package which is the wrong version.

Thanks a lot,
Michal.

Comment: What did you do to achieve this? Show your code/efforts here.StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you have a problem with your code, please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Well, I am trying to use an external tool, called Oncotator. This tool has some dependencies, some of them of a specific version (for example, pysam version 0.7.5). These versions are not available via 'conda install', so I installed them via 'pip install -e package_dir'. But the tool fails to run, and report on '_open() got an unexpected keyword argument \'encoding\'', which according to answers in forums it happens because using a wrong version of dependent packages, And as I wrote, indeed in 'conda list' I cannot see these packages.

Comment: I finally managed to do that via 'python install setup.py'. Still don't know why it didn't work with pip, though.